# Отправить запрос с куками и получить ответ

Tags: c#, wpf

Здравствуйте! Столкнулась с проблемой получения информации по запросу.
Отправляю куки на сервер, приходит ответ 200, но мне приходят только заголовки, как получить основное тело? Спасибо!

```
public async void GetData(string sessionId, string tokenId, string adress)
    {
        var baseAddress = new Uri(Settings.Default.api_url);
        using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler { UseCookies = true })
        using (var client = new HttpClient(handler) { BaseAddress = baseAddress })
        {
            var message = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, adress);
            message.Headers.Add("Cookies", "PHPSESSID=" + sessionId + "; CSRF_TOKEN=" + tokenId);
            var result = await client.SendAsync(message);
            result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        }
    }
```

Comment: `await result.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync` пробовали?

Comment: Да, приходят только заголовки, основного тела нет (в ответе должен придти сгенерированный json ответ)

Comment: А что именно приходит в потоке? Как вы читаете информацию оттуда? Дайте код.

Comment: Это и есть весь код. он содержит переменные PHPSESSID, CSRF_TOKEN и адрес, откуда получать инфу

Comment: Дело в том, что я не могу получить контент страницы, пока не отправлю куки, как подтверждение авторизации

Comment: Не, это не может быть _весь_ код, вы ж в вашем коде не читаете контент из `result`. Раз вы говорите, что контент не приходит, покажите, как вы его читаете. Если это реально весь код, добавьте чтение контента.

Comment: мой вопрос и обстоит в том, чтобы получить контент, я могу понять, что мне делать дальше

Comment: Тогда возвращаемся к моему первому комментарию. Что находится в стриме, который возвращается из `await result.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync`?

Comment: Ваш код отображает то же самое, что и мой "await client.SendAsync(message);"

Comment: @Vlad Я пытаюсь получить инфу по определенной ссылке, но доступ к ней проверяется сессией. Может у Вас имеется пример кода, который позволит мне отправить на нужный мне адрес куки и получить данные, которые мне нужны?

Comment: Vlad пытается намекнуть что в вашем примере кода нет собственно кода чтения тела ответа. И этот код должен выглядеть await result.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync и чтение с этого stream

Comment: @vitidev именно это я и прошу подсказать )

Comment: var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();  и все

Comment: @vitidev Спасибо большое, помогло!

Comment: @vitidev: Лучше было бы стрим скормить JSON-парсеру, меньше нагрузка на память.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решен  `var content = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();` 
Спасибо!